# Passing for loop using non-integers to awk

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I am trying to write code which will achieve:
Where $7 is less than $i (0 - 1 in increments of 0.05), print the line and pass to word count. The way I tried to do this was:

```
for i in $(seq 0 0.05 1); do awk '{if ($7 <= $i) print $0}' file.txt | wc -l ; done
```

This just ends up returning the word count of the full file (~40 million lines) for each instance of $i. When, for example using $7 <= 0.00, it should be returning ~67K.

I feel like there may be a way to do this within awk, but I have not seen any suggestions which allow for non-integers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [google "awk is not shell"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22awk+is+not+shell%22)

Comment: You will need to pass $i to awk as a variable with -v

Comment: I have done so now Ed, thanks. Prior to posting here, I did not know that this is why the problem had arisen, otherwise my Google exploits might have been more fruitful!! But I know now and shall spread the word to anyone else who encounters this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass $i to awk as a variable with -v and so:

```
 for i in $(seq 0 0.05 1); do awk -v i=$i '{if ($7 <= i) print $0}' file.txt | wc -l ; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not know about -v. My googling had led me down the awk 'BEGIN { while (getline < "'"$INPUTFILE"'") {     path, which seemed to be getting ever more elaborate! I am glad there is a parsimonious way of achieving the same result!!

Comment: Depending on the structure of the data in your file, you could also use a complete awk solution and negate the need to use the bash for loop

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will check this out for the future.

Comment: @LynseyHall FYI you could do all of this in 1 call to 1 simple awk script - no shell loops (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) or pipes or additional tools required. If you're interested in doing that then post a followup question with a [mcve] showing concise, testable sample input and expected output. btw since awk is not C, in idiomatic awk `'{if ($7 <= i) print $0}'` would be written as just `'$7 <= i'`.

Answer (score 0):

Some made up data:

```
$ cat file.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7    a b c d e f
1 2 3 4 5 6 0.6  a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 0.57 a b c d e f g h i j
1 2 3 4 5 6 1    a b c d e f g
1 2 3 4 5 6 0.21 a b
1 2 3 4 5 6 0.02 x y z
1 2 3 4 5 6 0.00 x y z l j k
```

One possible 100% `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN { line_count=0 }

{ printf "================= %s\n",$0

  for (i=0; i<=20; i++)
     { if ($7 <= i/20)
         { printf "matching seq : %1.2f\n",i/20
           line_count++
           seq_count[i]++
           next
          }
     }
}

END { printf "=================\n\n"

      for (i=0; i<=20; i++)
         { if (seq_count[i] > 0)
             { printf "seq = %1.2f : %8s (count)\n",i/20,seq_count[i] }
         }

      printf "\nseq =  all : %8s (count)\n",line_count
    }
' file.txt


# the output:
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    a b c d e f
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 0.6  a b c
matching seq : 0.60
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 0.57 a b c d e f g h i j
matching seq : 0.60
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 1    a b c d e f g
matching seq : 1.00
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 0.21 a b
matching seq : 0.25
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 0.02 x y z
matching seq : 0.05
================= 1 2 3 4 5 6 0.00 x y z l j k
matching seq : 0.00
=================

seq = 0.00 :        1 (count)
seq = 0.05 :        1 (count)
seq = 0.25 :        1 (count)
seq = 0.60 :        2 (count)
seq = 1.00 :        1 (count)

seq =  all :        6 (count)
```

- `BEGIN { line_count=0 }` : initialize a total line counter
- `print` statement is merely for debug purposes; will print out every line from file.txt as it's processed
- `for (i=0; i<=20; i++)` : depending on implementation, some versions of `awk` may have rounding/accuracy problems with non-integer numbers in sequences (eg, increment by 0.05), so we'll use whole integers for our sequence, and divide by 20 (for this particular case) to provide us with our 0.05 increments during follow-on testing
- `$7 <= i/20` : if field #7 is less than or equal to (i/20) ...
- `printf "matching seq ...` : print the sequence value we just matched on (i/20)
- `line_count++` : add '1' to our total line counter
- `seq_count[i]++` : add '1' to our sequence counter array
- `next` : break out of our sequence loop (since we found our matching sequence value (i/20), and process the next line in the file
- `END ...` : print out our line counts
- `for (x=1; ...) / if / printf` : loop through our array of sequences, printing the line count for each sequence (i/20)
- `printf "\nseq = all...` : print out our total line count

NOTE: Some of the `awk` code can be further reduced but I'll leave this as is since it's a little easier to understand if you're new to `awk`.

One (obvious?) benefit of a 100% `awk` solution is that our sequence/looping construct is internal to `awk` thus allowing us to limit ourselves to one loop through the input file (file.txt); when the sequence/looping construct is outside of `awk` we find ourselves having to process the input file once for each pass through the sequence/loop (eg, for this exercise we would have to process the input file **21 times !!!**).

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of guesswork as to what you actually want to accomplish, I came up with this:

```
awk '{ for (i=20; 20*$7<=i && i>0; i--) bucket[i]++ }
    END { for (i=1; i<=20; i++) print bucket[i] " lines where $7 <= " i/20 }'
```

With the mock data from [mark's second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965673/874188) I get this output:

```
2 lines where $7 <= 0.05
2 lines where $7 <= 0.1
2 lines where $7 <= 0.15
2 lines where $7 <= 0.2
3 lines where $7 <= 0.25
3 lines where $7 <= 0.3
3 lines where $7 <= 0.35
3 lines where $7 <= 0.4
3 lines where $7 <= 0.45
3 lines where $7 <= 0.5
3 lines where $7 <= 0.55
5 lines where $7 <= 0.6
5 lines where $7 <= 0.65
5 lines where $7 <= 0.7
5 lines where $7 <= 0.75
5 lines where $7 <= 0.8
5 lines where $7 <= 0.85
5 lines where $7 <= 0.9
5 lines where $7 <= 0.95
6 lines where $7 <= 1
```